# Yii2 - Model: find where two different dates are in range

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, yii2-model

I want to select items which are in a range of two different dates (`datetime` type in Database). In this case want to select all items in range of `dateStart` and `dateEnd`.

#### Example table data:

```
id | dateStart  | dateEnd
---+------------+-----------+
3  | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-07
6  | 2017-01-06 | 2017-01-10
8  | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-11
11 | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-04
12 | 2017-01-04 | 2017-01-10
15 | 2017-01-04 | 2017-01-18
17 | 2017-01-08 | 2017-01-10
25 | 2017-01-12 | 2017-01-15
31 | 2017-01-11 | 2017-01-24
```

#### Image for clarification:

[image]

---

Please note that I **don't want** to search between dates like:

```
Model::find()
    ->where(['between', 'dateStart', "2017-01-06", "2017-02-11"])
    ->all();
```

.. because `between` is not `in range`.

#### Using between results in this wrong output:

```
id | dateStart  | dateEnd
---+------------+-----------+
6  | 2017-01-06 | 2017-01-10
8  | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-11
11 | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-04
12 | 2017-01-04 | 2017-01-10
15 | 2017-01-04 | 2017-01-18
```

## E.g. preferred ouput:

The selected (based on the table data above) items by searching startDate >= `2017-01-05`and endDate <= `2017-01-11`  should look like this:

```
id | dateStart  | dateEnd
---+------------+-----------+
3  | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-07
6  | 2017-01-06 | 2017-01-10
8  | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-11
12 | 2017-01-04 | 2017-01-10
15 | 2017-01-04 | 2017-01-18
17 | 2017-01-08 | 2017-01-10
31 | 2017-01-11 | 2017-01-24
```

---

#### Note: I'am looking for an answer based on Yii2 ActiveRecord models.

Comment: could you explai  the difference of one  day  for the dates in between sample   and the dates in your searching sample ?  .. i don't understand the difference you assign to between and the your search sample >= and <= is how between work.. fo what i now .

Comment: @scaisEdge Please take a look at the picture, it does explain it. I also added an ouput example when using `between`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ActiveRecord you can do like this sequence of clauses ->orWhere:

```
$dateStart = '2017-01-05';
$dateEnd = '2017-01-11';

Model::find()
   ->orWhere(['between', 'dateEnd', $dateStart , $dateEnd]) 
   ->orWhere(['between', 'dateStart', $dateStart , $dateEnd]) 
   ->orWhere(['and', "dateEnd>='".$dateEnd."'", "dateStart<='".$dateStart ."'"])
   ->all();
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a yii2 active record model solution. I allready discovered this solution in the web. I'm not looking for an SQL solution. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Do you need exactly Active Record? I'm afraid of AR doesn't have such opportunities. But with DAO (not plain SQL), you can use Query Builder. Using this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#appending-conditions ; Query Builder is appropriate tool for complex queries.

Comment: Oleg, yea I know but maybe there is a solution based on operators - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail so .. I think it is possible with AR. Maybe by using `<>` operator.

Comment: ->orWhere(['between', 'dateEnd', $dateLeft, $dateRight])
->orWhere(['between', 'dateStart', $dateLeft, $dateRight])
->orWhere(['and', "dateEnd>=$dateRight", "dateStart<=$dateLeft"]);

try like this if possible

Comment: Great, this works like a charm. Could you update your answer? =)